# There does not exist an enumerable infinite $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: measure-theory

I would like to prove that it is not possible find an infinite enumerable $\sigma$-algebra.  Assume the contrary, that is, $(X,\mathcal{F})$ is a measurable space with $\mathcal{F} = \{ A_i : i \in \mathbb{N}\}$ enumerable $\sigma$-algebra. Then there is a bijection

$$\phi:\mathbb{N} \to \mathcal{F}$$

I can construct a new function

$$\varphi : 2^{\mathbb{N}} \to \mathcal{F}$$
$$\varphi(M) = \bigcup_{i \in M} A_i, \hbox{ for every } M \in 2^{\mathbb{N}}$$

Now, if the $\varphi$ function is injective, then $\mathcal{F}$ will not be enumerable, because  $2^{\mathbb{N}}$ is not enumerable. But I can not prove the  injetivity of the $\varphi$ function.  Some idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you describe is in fact not injective - for instance if $A_i\subseteq A_j$, $j\in L$, and and $M=L\cup\{i\}$, then $\varphi(M)=\varphi(L)$. So the issue is that the elements in the $\sigma$-algebra can overlap with each other.

The map $\varphi$ *would* be injective if $A_i\cap A_j=\emptyset$ whenever $i\not=j$ (do you see why?). This suggests the following idea:

> Find some $\{B_1, B_2, ...\}\subseteq\mathcal{F}$ such that (the $B_i$s are nonempty and) $B_i\cap B_j=\emptyset$ whenever $i\not=j$; then let $\psi(M)=\bigcup_{i\in M} B_i$ for $M\in 2^\mathbb{N}$.

So it all boils down to constructing that family of disjoint $B_i$s. Do you see how to do this?

Comment: Yes. I can do $B_1 = A_1 - \bigcup_{i > 1}A_i$, $B_2 = A_2 - \bigcup_{i > 2}A_i$, etc. Can I do this?

Comment: The unique posible problem can arise if the $\mathcal{F}$ is a monotone sequence. But a monotone class can not be $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: @orrillo No, that attempt won't work - e.g. what prevents $B_1$ from being empty (do you see how that affects injectivity)? And what prevents, say, $B_1=B_2$? (And I'm not sure what your second comment means - it is true that no infinite monotone sequence of sets can be a $\sigma$-algebra, but how is that relevant?)

Comment: If $\mathcal{F} = \mathcal{M} \bigcup \cup\{A_i\}_{i= 1}^{K}$, where $\mathcal{M}$ is a monote class, I can not construct the $\{B_1, B_2,....\}$. But in this case, $\mathcal{F}$ will not be a $\sigma$-algebra. So, I need some infinite list of sets (each not empty) not nested (all diferents mutually) $\{A_1 , A_2,...\}$ in $\mathcal{F}$ to construct each $B_i$ as above.

Comment: But, I thik that there is some more easy way to construct the $\{B_1,B_2,...\}$ mutually disjoint. I will attempt induction aproach.